# Can the Flash and Superman converse at supersonic speed?

Tags: dc, superman, the-flash

If they're both moving faster than sound, obviously they shouldn't be able to talk to each other.

But have they ever?

And is it ever explained?

Comment: Do you mean talk normally while they're running/flying at supersonic speed, or standing still with their lips moving at supersonic speed?

Comment: In real life, can a pilot at Mach speed talk into his comm system?

Comment: Are we talking pre-Crisis? Earth-One Superman could do just about anything in the absence of magic, kryptonite, and red solar rays. I imagine the writers would have had him use his super-ventriloquism (no, really!) and had him read The Flash's lips to make it a two-way conversation, if they bothered to explain it at all. Such details were often ignored by or foreign to those involed.

Comment: @cde not quite the same thing, given that the air in the cockpit is (nearly) stationary with respect to the pilot.  In contrast, Superman, when moving at supersonic speed, is surrounded by air moving at supersonic speeds with respect to him, and that wind would snatch words away faster than they could propagate.

Comment: @Darael Actually cde's comparison is valid if you focus on the exact wording in the question (instead of its probable intent), their ability to be able to **talk** is the same as the pilot's. The only difference is that the pilot is able to **hear** and **be heard** (because radio transmissions are faster of course and answers will be able to catch up with him).

Comment: Also, http://i.imgur.com/esVdBZJ.jpg

Comment: @BMWurm Granted, but given that the OP almost certainly meant *communicate verbally*, rather than strictly *talk*, I stand by what I said.  Especially as actually it's much harder to talk with a strong wind on one's face than without, even ignoring whether or not one is heard (though super-resilience/speedforce probably nullifies that).  I like cde's latest response, though.

Comment: @Darael So do I. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As they move through a medium (air) faster than the speed of sound in that medium, they produce a conical shock wave. Inside the cone, you can hear them; outside it, you can't.

If they are travelling in the same direction, then they can't both be in the other's cone so, at most, one of them can hear the other (assuming they can filter out the noise produced by their own movement).

If they are moving in opposite directions, then they can be inside each others cones and can hear each other, but only sounds produced before they passed each other. In fact they would hear the sounds in reverse as they overtake and pass them (again assuming they could hear the sound through the noise of their own supersonic movement)

I can certainly imagine Superman's 'super hearing' being able to hear through the noise of their movement, and 'hearing fast things while going fast' is certainly the kind of thing the Flash ought to be able to do so the problem of hearing though the noise can probably be dismissed.

So if one is in the wake of the other, then **yes, they can hear the other speaking**. They won't be able to have a back and forth conversation though.

Of course they have held a conversation while running despite this in the *Superman: The Animated Series* episode "*Speed Demons*". It's not explained.

Comment: @sumelic Other than physics you mean?

Comment: @sumelic The powers do not, but we have to assume **sound** still behaves the same as in our world - and propagates "naturally" - or if not, that the difference is mentioned (and preferably explained) in the source material. Since it isn't, smithkim assumes *natural* conditions, otherwise we lack a frame of reference for the discussion.

Comment: Even if they didn't produce a shockwave somehow, sound's propagation from a supersonic source would still be conical in the same way.

Comment: Not just the animated series. The JL/JLU cartoon, various JL films, the comics. Basically all speedsters of various forms can communicate at supersonic speeds, physics be damned.

Answer (score 12):

**Yes**, they **can** and **have** done so in canon. And, yes, it has **been explained** by the writer(s).

In ***Superman #709***, in the *"Superman: Grounded"* Story Arc, they have what should  amount to a 5-minute conversation within the span of a millisecond.
During their conversation, *"the whole World has just frozen in place"* - it's also notable to mention that the entire conversation had also taken up the following 3 or 4 Comic Book pages of dialogue, as well. Ironically, this conversation brings up the things Flash, while moving faster than sound, spoke to Superman earlier in the comic to get his attention.

Here are the scans:
[image: Conversation Scan #1]
<sub>(source: [comicvine.com](https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/11113/111130781/3706710-4016045162-26290.jpg))</sub>

[image: Conversation Scan #2]
<sub>(source: [comicvine.com](https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/11113/111130781/3706711-0291563915-26290.jpg))</sub>

[image: Conversation Scan #3]
<sub>(source: [comicvine.com](https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/11113/111130781/3706712-1266030693-26290.jpg))</sub>

[image: Conversation Scan #4]
<sub>(source: [comicvine.com](https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/11113/111130781/3706713-9090819833-26290.jpg))</sub>

In these scans, you can see that the the background is essentially frozen throughout their conversation. The woman who spilled the coffee (and the coffee itself) in the first scan stays frozen through most panels and shows minimal movement at the end of the conversation when the Flash intervenes (it is unclear whether this is due to elapsed time or the Flash's intervention). Also, the kids seen looking at Superman and Flash (in the booth behind the Flash) in Panel 2 of Scan 1 are shown in the same position in Panel 4 of Scan 3 and with minimal (if any) movement in Panel 1 of Scan 4.

Here is a scan of Superman using his super-hearing to pinpoint Flash, who was speaking Kryptonian at **hyperspeed** and moving faster than sound (***Superman #709***):
[image: Superman hears Flash FTS]
<sub>(source: [comicvine.com](https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/6/60791/2167972-1725070-superman709_005.jpg))</sub>

Also, **the writer** of ***Superman #709***, Chris Roberson, had some interesting things to say, in regards Superman having to "speed up" his senses while using his Super-Speed. Not only does this interview actually confirm that Superman has massively beyond nanosecond-precise perception and reaction time - even up towards attosecond-precise, according to Roberson himself - but also brings out that there actually isn't any drawn out speed-up time for Super-Speed perceptions and reactions:

> ***"It's a fair question, to be sure. I wasn't thinking of Superman "activating" his superspeed perceptions, like it was a light switch that could be turned on and off, so much as it was shifting his perceptions to bring superspeed events and sounds into focus. Like the human eye looking at something small and close up and then adjusting when the viewer looks at something large and far away, I think Superman is perceiving all of these things, ALL of the time, and it's just a question of what he chooses to focus on. But I think Superman is also capable of focusing on macro-scale, "normal" speed events at a rate something similar to that in the typical human range, so that he wouldn't spend a subjective eternity between each word in every sentence that Lois says to him. Similarly, he can chose to perceive visual information much like we do, or he can expand his perceptions and see far into the electromagnetic spectrum, or narrow his focus far enough to see individual atoms. But just like he doesn't see Lois as merely a cloud of electrons, neutrons, and protons, he doesn't perceive every second as composed of a huge number of attosecond-scale events--unless he wants to, of course."***
>
> ***But that's just one fan's opinion, too!***
>
> ***Best,
> Chris Roberson***"

Of course, this doesn't make *physical* sense as sound moves at 343 m/s in air and therefore should necessitate a longer conversation time, but c'mon guys it's comics. Some physical laws have to be suspended.

**Extra:**
Here is a scan of Barry Allen talking to Wally West while moving near **lightspeed**, which is WAY faster than speed of sound (Also notice that Superman is able to perceive them):

[image: Flash conversation]
<sub>(source: [comicvine.com](https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/7/72524/3139608-0501469459-26301.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I like to think they're reading each other's lips.

Comment: They can also do that in [_Injustice_ #24](https://imgur.com/a/xYLDH).

Answer (score 1):

In [*DCeased #6*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCeased), after [Flash/Barry Allen](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Barry_Allen_(DCeased)) got turned into an [Anti-Living](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Anti-Living_(DCeased)), an infection comparable to being turned into a zombie, albeit the victim wants to spread death instead of feeding (either by killing or infecting the others), [Superman](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Kal-El_(DCeased)) had to resort to killing him.

Unfortunately for him, he got infected in the process. Upon seeing the wound on his chest, he flew as fast as possible to meet [Kid Flash/Wallace West](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wallace_R._West_(DCeased)).

[image: The picture depicts 5 panels from DCeased issue #6. The first two panels have Superman fly from the ocean to Kid Flash. Lois Lane, aka. the narrator, says: "I don't know how long Superman had. His body could obviously fight the infection longer than others. I don't know how long it seemed to him. A man who can move at those speeds... But with the time he had left... ...He crossed the world.". In the 4 later panels, everything is depicted in black and white, except for Superman and Kid Flash, which might be to depict the fact they are both moving at super speed. Superman tells the news about Flash's death, but also the fact that Superman himself was infected, to Kid Flash's horror. His last request is to ask if Kid Flash could possibly connect his relatives (his wife Lois, his mother, and his son Jon), so that he can bid them farewell, before the infection takes over him.]

The dialogue and the narration makes it clear to us that everything is happening very fast. Had Superman talked to Kid Flash at "normal speed", he most likely would have turned into an Anti-Living during the conversation (usually, it does not take long for someone who has been infected to turn). And with the assistance of Kid Flash who connected Superman's relatives into the speed force, he was able to say his good byes.

[image: Superman is having a last conversation with his adoptive mother, his wife Lois and his son Jonathan before he turns into an Anti-Living, thanking them for being there for him.]

The *DCeased* issues happened in an alternate Earth though, which means this Superman might have abilities that the one from the main universe does not. Plus they were not moving at supersonic speed, but only having a conversation at a faster than humanly possible speed.

Comment: I hesitated to post this because they aren't moving at supersonic speed. But I figured it's not so different from the other answer where they're discussing in a dinner while someone is falling.